# How to print or export as a picture a UML diagram created with Netbeans EasyUML plugin?

Tags: java, netbeans, export, uml, class-diagram

I am using EasyUML plugin in Netbeans (8.1) to generate and edit a UML class diagram that I would like to either print (to a PDF file) or export as a PNG or JPG preferably.

However, it seems that it is impossible to print the diagram since the File > Print command is greyed and I don't see any other mean to use that diagram elsewhere.

Is there a way to export/print the class diagram generated with EasyUML?

Comment: One hack-like solution might be to just take a screenshot (if your diagram fits on the screen).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's impossible to print a diagram from Netbeans, but you can export it to PNG: right click on the diagram and choose `"Export as image"`.

[image]

Comment: I was looking for the right place to make the "right click" and after some time I have found out that the right place to make right click is inside of the area of uml diagrams. Thanks.